# MySQL - SQL_BIG_SELECTS

Tags: mysql, select

Hey, I've been investigating SQL_BIG_SELECTS, but the MySQL documentation so far has been pretty unhelpful. I'm looking for some insight as to preventing errors like the one below from appearing.

> ERROR 1104: The SELECT would examine too many records and probably take a very long time.
>   Check your WHERE and use SET OPTION SQL_BIG_SELECTS=1 if the SELECT is ok

1. At how many rows does MySQL decide that a query is a "BIG SELECT"?
2. Will proper indexing usually solve this issue?
3. Is SQL_BIG_SELECTS considered a "last resort", or is it good practice?
4. How would someone set "SQL_BIG_SELECTS=1" in configuration (without having to execute the query)?
5. Are there any other alternatives worth knowing?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 43, accepted):

1. MySQL determines whether or not a query is a 'big select' based on the value of 'max_join_size'.  If the query is likely to have to examine more than this number of rows, it will consider it a 'big select'.  Use 'show variables' to view the value of the max join size.
2. I believe that indexing and particular a good where clause will prevent this problem from occuring.
3. SQL_BIG_SELECTS is used to prevent users from accidentally executing excessively large queries.  It is okay to set it to ON in mysql.cnf or using the command-line option at startup.
4. You can set SQL_BIG_SELECTS in my.cnf or at server startup.  It can also be set on a session basis with `SET SESSION SQL_BIG_SELECTS=1`.
5. Not that I can think of.  I would just check your query to make sure that you really need to use it.  Our servers have it turned on by default, and max_join_size is very large.

Comment: Setting correct indexes on tables used in 'join' can also solve the problem - just did so.

Comment: Thanks, this not only helped me solving my problem, but also optimizing my complete database structure!

Answer (score 2):

You *cannot* set [`SQL_BIG_SELECTS`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_sql_big_selects) in my.cnf or at server startup as it is a session only parameter. I am using MySQL 5.0.60.

Answer (score 1):

As someone has post before, you can not set SQL_BIG_SELECTS on my.cnf at server startup. This kind of variable does not support that.

I had a same problem with a Symfony application showing this annoying error:

```
The SELECT would examine more than MAX_JOIN_SIZE rows; check your WHERE and use SET SQL_BIG_SELECTS=1 or SET SQL_MAX_JOIN_SIZE=# if the SELECT is okay
```

But you can increase the number of varialbe

max_join_size which is related to sql_big_selects

I was able to fix it executing a command as privileged mysql user:

```
# SET GLOBAL max_join_size=18446744073709551615;
```

Or you can include it in my.cnf because max_join_size is allowed to set up in configuration file

Well, I hope this can help someone else.

Answer (score 1):

I had more than 2000k records in db, and my query was big-select with exhaustive comparison for duplication removal and updation of certain field...I was told the same by `mysql` (current version on answer date), and I ended up using `index` on 2 fields involved in `where` clause...this should help others too...steps which worked for me were:

1. Set Index on field
2. ANALYZE TABLE
3. run the query

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Following command works for me

```
SET GLOBAL max_join_size=18446744073709551615;
```

But what do i need to put in my.cnf file instead of the command?
Btw, i'm using "5.6.12 MySQL Community Server"

Answer (score -1):

```
SET SESSION SQL_BIG_SELECTS =1;# MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows).
SELECT a.`HACtrl` , b.`HBCtrl` , c.`HDCtrl`
FROM `HO110BLote` AS a
LEFT JOIN `HO113BPago` AS b ON ( b.HBHACtrl = a.HACtrl )
LEFT JOIN `HO113BRecibos` AS c ON ( c.HDHBCtrl = b.HBCtrl )
WHERE HAManzana = '03'
AND HALote = '09'
LIMIT 0 , 100
```

Comment: Please edit your answer and add some explanations to it. Thanks.