# Simple, but most likely an incorrect Join is giving a MAX_JOIN_SIZE error

Tags: sql, join

Probably a simple SQL query, but struggling as still learning

The following query runs fine:

```
SELECT NationalArea. * 
FROM NationalArea
WHERE NationalArea.AreaCode =  '01922'
```

This returns about 30 results.

This also runs fine:

```
SELECT DestinationNames.Name
FROM `DestinationNames` 
WHERE DestinationNames.AreaCode = '01922'
```

This returns just the one

I am trying to run a query that joins the two where the National Area will give a list of area codes and the destination will match those area codes with the names of the towns. The query I have is as follows:

```
SELECT NationalArea.*, DestinationNames.Name
FROM NationalArea
JOIN DestinationNames
ON NationalArea.AreaCode=DestinationNames.AreaCode
WHERE NationalArea.AreaCode =  '01922'
```

But I get the following error

> 1104 - The SELECT would examine more than MAX_JOIN_SIZE rows; check your WHERE and use SET SQL_BIG_SELECTS=1 or SET MAX_JOIN_SIZE=# if the SELECT is okay

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL MAX\_JOIN\_SIZE errors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/966815/mysql-max-join-size-errors). The solution is also contained within the error message.

Answer (score 2):

You can display the current value with

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%MAX_JOIN_SIZE%';
```

You can change it with:

```
SET MAX_JOIN_SIZE = 100
```

Or skip the check entirely with (run this as a separate command before your query):

```
SET SQL_BIG_SELECTS = 1
```

But I would first examine why your join returns more than that.  It doesn't look like it should.  The default value of max_join_size is 4294967295!

Comment: Thanks for answering - I think its definitely my join but I can't see where. I am only expecting it to return 30 results as the where statement WHERE NationalArea.AreaCode =  '01922' on the NationalArea table only returns 30 and I'm only joining the same Areacode numbers from the other table?

Comment: The query in your question looks OK.  I'd examine the data in the two tables?

Comment: Not sure if its anymore help, but when I put SET SQL_BIG_SELECTS = 1 in front the query I now get: 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT NationalArea.*, DestinationNames.Name FROM NationalArea JOIN Destinatio' at line 2. Its really odd, as the separate queries work fine but join them together and it fails - ill keep playing. Thanks.

Comment: Are you putting `;` after `SET SQL_BIG_SELECTS = 1`?

Comment: Nope, sorry, adding that interestingly now it works! and only gives the 30 results I was expecting. My SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%MAX_JOIN_SIZE%'; is showing 900,000, which seems more then enough as one table has about 16,000 and the other 10,000 records, unless its a multiplication of them both, I will then need to up it to above 160,000,000? I used SET MAX_JOIN_SIZE = 4294967295 but it still shows on 900000, maybe something set by the hosting provider? You where on the right track the whole time :)