# How to save, handle the order total amount in an orders, ordersDetails schema?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database-design

When I started designing my application database schema few months ago I have been told not to store the same data/*calculated data* in more than one place in the database(normalization). If I do, I will make a scope of bugs when I update the data in one place and left the other without updating. So I did an orders table and ordersDetails table. Something like this..

```
-- orders table
+-----+---------+----------+
| ID  | clintID |   date   |
+-----+---------+----------+
|  1  |    1    |2018-02-22|
|  2  |    1    |2018-02-23|
|  3  |    2    |2018-02-24|
+-----+---------+----------+
-- orderDetail table
+-----+---------+------------+----------+----------+
| ID  | orderID | itemNumber | quantity | unitPrice|
+-----+---------+------------+----------+----------+
|  1  |    1    |   12345    |    3     |  100.75  |
|  2  |    1    |   12346    |    3     |  100.75  |
|  3  |    2    |   12347    |    3     |  100.75  |
|  4  |    2    |   12345    |    3     |  100.75  |
|  5  |    3    |   12347    |    3     |  100.75  |
|  6  |    3    |   12345    |    3     |  100.75  |
+-----+---------+------------+----------+----------+
```

And to make the the queries easier for me I made a view "allOrdersSummary" like

```
-- allOrdersSummary
SELECT 
    orders.*, SUM(orderDetail.quantity * orderDetail.unitPrice) totalAmount
FROM orders INNER JOIN orderDetail ON orders.ID = orderDetail.orderID 
GROUP BY orders.ID;
```

and I used this view later for my queries, but now I started to get the [MAX_JOIN_SIZE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/943423/mysql-the-select-would-examine-more-than-max-join-size-rows) error.

So I thought of saving the calculated total order amount along with the orders table `ID, clintID, date, totalAmount` and whenever I change something in the `orderDeatils` table I update the calculated `totalAmount` column in the orders table, I don't know if this is good or bad!

This problem -*I don't know if this is considered a problem or not*- is encountered many times, for example to know the unread messages of the client making the request I have to do `sum(messages) unread from messages where to = ? and isRead = 0`

**A)** should I make another column for calculated `totalAmount` in the orders table or it is a normal thing in databases to calculate the `totalAmount` from the `orderDetails` table every time I need it ?

**B)** If you recommend making another column in the orders table, what is the best way to update it every time a change happens in the `orderDetails` table ? should I update it at the PHP layer whenever I update the `orderDetails` table, or this is something that needs a stored procedure ?

Comment: Just to verify something, my MAX_JOIN_SIZE is set to 18,446,744,073,709,551,616. That's quite big. What's yours?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I checked it now, it's `1000000000`

Comment: Still quite large, but compared to mine tiny. Why this number? (there must always be a good reason why you configure your server to a non-default value). See: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_join_size

Comment: How large is the data?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Hmmm. my number looks more like human made. I think my [hosting company set this as a default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/966815/mysql-max-join-size-errors) . I will change it to the default [18446744073709551615](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_join_size)

Comment: @GordonLinoff just sample data, the orders table has 100 rows! and the ordersDetails has about 500. But I use the view in a very long sql query (it's Explain statement gets 27 rows)

Comment: That's a complex query. Yes, I would set it back to the default, although your hosting company might have set this value because of the lackluster performance of their servers. I would only use pre-calculated values when the queries start to take too long, and you cannot afford a better server.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Sir, do you recommend saving the calculated total with the orders table if the data became to be large ? or you completely refuse that calculated total column ?

Comment: @Accountantم - Essentially everyone leaves `max_join_size` at just under 2^64.  1 billion is unusual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is normal to store pre-calculated values, based on other data in the database, in a database. But not necessarily for the reason you mention. I never had a problem with `MAX_JOIN_SIZE`.

The main, and probably only, reason for storing calculated values is speed. So you do it for values that don't change that often and that may be used in queries that use a lot of data and may therefore be too slow if you didn't use them.

For instance: If you want to know the average value of all the orders in your database the query would be a lot faster if you already have the order totals.

Why, and how, you update the values is completely up to you. However **you have got to be consistent about it**. If you use the MVC pattern it would make sense to integrate it in the controller. Or in simple terms: Whenever a form is submitted that could change one of the values, out of which the pre-calculated value is computed, you need to recompute it.

This is a clear demonstration where 'normalization' is not entirely maintained. It's not really pretty, but sometimes worth it. You could, of course, argue, that the calculated value represents 'new' information, and therefore does not offend against 'normalization'.

Answer (score 1):

You have an "inflate-deflate" problem.

1. `JOIN` the two tables to make a much larger temporary table.
2. `GROUP BY` to shrink back to one row per row of the original (`orders`) table.

This avoids the problem:

```
SELECT  *,
        ( SELECT SUM(quantity * unitPrice
              FROM orderDetail  WHERE orderID = orders.ID
        ) AS totalAmount
    FROM  orders;
```

Please let me know how your experience is with this one.  It is one of the simplest examples of the inflate-deflate problem.

Comment: No Mr. Rick, this is the first time I see the term "inflate-deflate" problem. I always join, and group. [When I started to learn and make my own system 18 months ago](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/147295/my-included-in-every-script-file), I spent my time on everything the system needs PHP, JavaScript, HTML, CSS. All I wanted from the database is to just work! I never cared about scaling or performance, but now I'm focusing entirely on learning how to tune my database for performance and I hope I can learn it fast with minimal changes in the application code.

Comment: He, he.  I made up the term.  Sometimes I call it "explode-implode".  I am hoping to add it to my optimization/scaling site - mysql.rjweb.org - once I get a good handle on how to describe it and explain the generic cause plus provide a generic solution.