# Error SET SQL_BIG_SELECTS=1 or SET MAX_JOIN_SIZE=#

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am facing a problem with my query ...

```
SELECT 
keywords.keyword,
keywords.keyid,
sources.s_title,
sources.s_disc,
sources.s_link,
sources.sourceid,
sources.s_link
FROM link_ks
INNER JOIN keywords ON link_ks.keyid = keywords.keyid
INNER JOIN sources ON link_ks.sourceid = sources.sourceid
INNER JOIN thumbsup_items ON link_ks.sourceid = thumbsup_items.name
WHERE link_ks.keyid = :keyid 
order by thumbsup_items.votes_up desc,thumbsup_items.votes_down asc,(thumbsup_items.votes_up+thumbsup_items.votes_down) desc
```

Every thing was good when database was small but as database become big I am getting this error

```
 The SELECT would examine more than MAX_JOIN_SIZE rows; check your WHERE and use SET
 SQL_BIG_SELECTS=1 or SET MAX_JOIN_SIZE=# if the SELECT is okay
```

But when I remove

```
 order by thumbsup_items.votes_up desc,thumbsup_items.votes_down asc,
(thumbsup_items.votes_up+thumbsup_items.votes_down) desc
```

Problem gets solved ... But `order by` is important for this query ...

is there any other way to write this query or how can I solve this problem ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the 
`MAX_JOIN_SIZE` and `SQL_BIG_SELECTS` won't let you  run long queries which will hang the server.

Use this before running the query:

```
 SET OPTION SQL_BIG_SELECTS = 1
```

or use this:

```
SET SQL_BIG_SELECTS=1
```

[chek this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950465/mysql-sql-big-selects)

Comment: Thx it work but i have a question ... will this slow down the query or  will it put load on server ? and is this safe to use ?

Comment: this is just to let you run big query , nothing to do with safe to use or slowing down the query. the sharing hosts making having this to dont hang the server on long queries.

Answer (score 1):

for those, like me, who are seeing this for the first time...

this =>

$setupMySql = mysql_query(" SET OPTION SQL_BIG_SELECTS = 1 " )
       or die('Cannot complete SETUP BIG SELECTS because: ' . mysql_error());