# HOW to get round MAX_JOIN_SIZE with cakephp v3.x

Tags: mysql, cakephp

I am getting this the following MAX_JOIN_SIZE error when I deploy my cakephp v3 app to shared hosting:

```
    Error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1104 The SELECT would examine more than MAX_JOIN_SIZE rows; check your WHERE and use SET SQL_BIG_SELECTS=1 or SET MAX_JOIN_SIZE=# if the SELECT is okay
```

This seems like a common problem, but can anyone tell me how to get round this when using cakephp v3.x?  I have tried putting the following code in app/src/Model/AppModel.php:

```
    function beforeFind()   {
        $this->query('SET SQL_BIG_SELECTS=1');
    }
```

but this doesn't seem to have any effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CakePHP 3.0 doesn't use an `AppModel` anymore. You really should [read the migration guide](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/appendices/3-0-migration-guide.html). Implement it via an event listener on `Model.beforeFind` or as a behavior.

Further setting SQL_BIG_SELECTS to 1 seems like **bad practice** to me. You should not work around the symptoms but fix the cause: *Figure out what's wrong with your query*.

See [MySQL - SQL_BIG_SELECTS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950465/mysql-sql-big-selects) which has a good answer.

Comment: I took your advice and found another way to achieve what I wanted to do. My original solution was more elegant and wasn't a ridiculous number of joins, but hey ho...