# MYSQL/PHP: MYSQL query throwing Big_Select error depending on Order By clause

Tags: php, mysql, sql-order-by

I have a query that runs fine when I use any of several different `ORDER BY` clauses such as by a date or by an alphabetical string.  When I try to order by a float value or an int value, however, I am suddenly getting the following error:

```
The SELECT would examine more than MAX_JOIN_SIZE rows; check your WHERE and use SET SQL_BIG_SELECTS=1 or SET MAX_JOIN_SIZE=# if the SELECT is okay
```

The int values are integers.  The float values are decimals.  Ordering by either however, is yielding the above error.

I have tried adding both the `Big_Selects` and `Max_Join_Size` statements as setup but they are not fixing the error leading me to believe something is going wrong behind the scenes with the float and int fields.

I also added an index to the int field to no avail.

Has anyone encountered an error such as this or have suggestions about what to do?

Comment: Check this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/943423/mysql-the-select-would-examine-more-than-max-join-size-rows

Comment: I followed those suggestions of adding indexes and setting big selects and max join size but am still getting error. What I don't understand is why changing the ORDER BY clause would have any affect not he JOIN